# Why .on() doesn't support delegation(future element) while using multiple event handlers?

Tags: jquery

**Using .live() :**

```
<input type="button" value="button" />

$(":input[type=button]").live({
      click: function() {
            $(this).after('<input type="button" value="new" />');
      },
      mouseover: function() {
            //do something
      },
      mouseout: function() {
            //do something
      }
    });
```

**DEMO :** http://jsfiddle.net/F9gC4

Here delegation works fine. If we click 'button' or 'new', new button element will be created.

**Using .on() :**

```
<input type="button" value="button" />

$(":input[type=button]").live({
      click: function() {
            $(this).after('<input type="button" value="new" />');
      },
      mouseover: function() {
            //do something
      },
      mouseout: function() {
            //do something
      }
    });
```

**DEMO :** http://jsfiddle.net/CB8fh

Here delegation doesn't work. 'new' button click doesn't create element(can't fire)

So how can we use .on() multiple event handlers with delegation(future element)?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).on({
      click: function() {
            $(this).after('<input type="button" value="new" />');
      },
      mouseover: function() {
            //do something
      },
      mouseout: function() {
            //do something
      }
}, ':input[type=button]');​
```

For delegation to work with created/future elements you need to attach the event to document and use the 'selector' argument of the .on function to target the event. Not tested, but in theory should work! See documentation for [the on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and also [the documentation for live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has a section on moving to the .on function.

**Edit** just wanted to add, as @Joy said in his answer, you don't need to attach to `document`, the closer to the target element you delegate to the better (although you need to be sure that element will not be affected by ajax/dom changes that might remove the event handler).

Comment: This part "you need to attach the event to document" isn't technically true. You only need to attach the event handler to an element that is a. always going to be present and b. contain all of the elements that you'll want to delegate the event to. `document` is the best choice for examples because it's always going to meet those two criteria, but if you can identify an element that's more specific in your actual HTML document, you should use that instead.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist You're right, I just finished updating the post as you replied :D

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind the event to a parent element in case of `$.on` like this

```
$(document).on({
  click: function() {
        $(this).after('<input type="button" value="new" />');
  },
  mouseover: function() {
        //do something
  },
  mouseout: function() {
        //do something
  }
},':input[type=button]');​
```

In this case I am binding to `document`, you can bind to any `parent` that will always exist in the dom.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/CB8fh/2/)

Reference: [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)